# What is the shortest way to get the string content of a HttpPostedFile in C#

Tags: c#, string, httppostedfile

I have an HttpPostedFile object and just need to extract the content of the posted file.

I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.80).aspx) but that's a very long process to just obtain a string with the content.

Is there any shorter way? (Preferably, a one line instruction.)

Comment: +1, especially for following up with the actual problem/ solution.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
var str = new StreamReader(postedFile.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

[StreamReader.ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that worked flawless. I was trying that before making the question but I was getting an empty string so wasn't sure that was the correct way.The problem was that I needed to set the position of the reader back to 0 (`postedFile.InputStream.Position = 0`) as this was the second time on the code reading the content. Thanks again @LenielMacaferi and @AlexeiLevenkov